# converting a DataTable to an array using select

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am trying to convert a DataTable to array using `Select` and `toArray` I did this:

```
List<int> LevelsArray = CardServiceDetailsDt.Select("LEVEL_ID").ToList<int>();
```

but an error is accrued

```
'System.Data.DataRow[]' does not contain a definition for 'ToArray' and the best extension method overload 'System.Linq.Enumerable.ToArray<TSource>(System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<TSource>)' has some invalid arguments
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Select` will filter the rows for you but looks like you want to get all the values in one column, so you can't use `Select`, try this instead:

```
var rows = CardServiceDetailsDt.AsEnumerable()
                 .Select(row=>row.Field<long>("LEVEL_ID")).ToArray();
```

Comment: it gives me a the specific cast is not valid

Comment: @Sora what's the actual type of `LEVEL_ID`?

Comment: it's ok i figure out that the actual type of `LEVEL_ID` is `long`

Answer (score 0):

You can use `AsEnumerable()` to call `ToArray()` also use Field to ge the column value of datatable.

```
ObjDt.AsEnumerable().Select
            (r => r.Field<string>("LEVEL_ID")).ToArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var array = CardServiceDetailsDt.Rows[i]
                                .ItemArray
                                .Select(x => x.ToString())
                                .ToArray();
```

i is the index of the row.